# WPF DataContext not updating children

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, custom-controls

I am trying to use data binding on my first custom user control in WPF. Unfortunately the UI never receives updates.

Declaration of custom user control:

```
<views:EpisodeDetailsUserControl 
    x:Name="EpisodeDetailsUserControl" 
    DataContext="{Binding Episode}"/>
```

Custom user control xaml (snippet):

```
    <Label 
        x:Name="TvShowNameLabel" 
        Grid.Row="0" 
        Grid.Column="1" 
        DataContext="{Binding TvShowName}" />

    <Label 
        x:Name="SeasonIdLabel" 
        Grid.Row="1" 
        Grid.Column="1" 
        DataContext="{Binding SeasonId}" />
```

I expected the user control to be updated when:

```
    private void DowloadedEpisodesListViewSelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var episode = DowloadedEpisodesListView.SelectedItem as IEpisode;

        if (episode != null)
        {
            EpisodeDetailsUserControl.DataContext = episode; // <======
        }
    }
```

For completeness, IEpisode

```
public interface IEpisode
{
    string FileName { get; }
    string FullPath { get; }
    string Directory { get; }
    string Extension { get; }

    string TvShowName { get; set; }
    int SeasonId { get; set; }
    int Id { get; set; }
    string Name { get; }

    bool IsValid { get; }
    string NewFileName { get; }
    string RenameProposal { get; }
}
```

But no luck, nothing happens.

Can somebody point me in the right direction?

Comment: Is the class that implements IEpisode also implementing INotifyPropertyChanged?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should bind label `Content` property instead of `DataContext`:

```
<Label x:Name="SeasonIdLabel" 
       Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" 
       Content="{Binding SeasonId}" />
```

Also, you probably could bind `EpisodeDetailsUserControl.DataContext` to `DowloadedEpisodesListView` directly to get rid of that event handler in code-behind:

```
DataContext="{Binding ElementName=DowloadedEpisodesListView, Path=SelectedItem}"
```

Comment: Ahhhh!! So that's how it they meant it to work! thx for both the answer and that tip! Both work fine, I did the same ugly trick in other places, so I can get rid of more redundant code-behind. nr1! Thx!